# Deleting environment variables within kdb instance

Tags: linux, kdb

How can I unset environment variables within a kdb instance?

I can do `` setenv[`abc;""] `` which will give the same output in kdb as if it doesn't exist, but behind the scenes is the environment variable actually deleted, or is it just set to be empty?

Also, does the system command run in a separate OS terminal?

```
q)setenv[`acc;321]
q)getenv`acc
"321"
q)system"unset acc"
q)getenv`acc
"321"
```

similarly:

```
q)system"export adc=123; echo $adc"
"123"
q)system"echo $adc"
""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can remove an environment variable defined in q as you've outlined.

> is the environment variable actually deleted, or is it just set to be empty?

It's just set to empty i.e. still defined on the process.

Using `strace -tTy -p <pid>` you can see when running system commands that e.g. vfork is utilised, in that system calls are executed in a temporary child clone.